# SORT a QUERY with IF statement in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, if-statement, google-sheets, select, graph

I'm trying to select cells in column C6:C (Category) where the value of the cells in column D6:D (Status) = "Sold". Then I want to sort that resulting list by occurrence.

I want to do this so I can make a column graph that displays the data from highest to lowest occurrence.

I've figured out how to do this 2 separate ways but I feel like there has to be a simpler, less messy way? Maybe?

Here's a link to a test area for reference. You can edit.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/169VQmPLNGm0ioGctCti5wu9_o5hC6k_3wmb7AKYPHuA/edit?usp=sharing

P.S., if you know a simpler way to edit a graph to get the same result without doing all this data sorting first, that'd be great too. LOL.

Here are the two ways I've tried.

**WAY NO. 1 (Two steps)**

First, select all Category cells where Status = Sold (F6:F)

`=ArrayFormula({if(D6:D="Sold",C6:C,"")})`

Second, sort the resulting list (G6:G)

`=sort(F6:F, if(len(F6:F),countif(F6:F,F6:F),), 0, 1, 1 )`

**WAY NO. 2 (Single step but kinda messy?)**

Select and sort cells all at once (J6:J)

`=SORT(ArrayFormula({if(D6:D="Sold",C6:C,"")}), if(len(ArrayFormula({if(D6:D="Sold",C6:C,"")})),countif(ArrayFormula({if(D6:D="Sold",C6:C,"")}),ArrayFormula({if(D6:D="Sold",C6:C,"")})),), 0, 1, 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=tocol(choosecols(sort(let(Σ,if(D6:D="Sold",C6:C,),{Σ,countif(Σ,Σ)}),2,0),1),1)
```

[image]